# How do i manipulate/modify the existing nested python dictionary 'dict' and have the output format as needed below?

Tags: python, xml, dictionary, parsing

I have a simple function here to parse through an xml by parsing it to the Elementree module and returning a dictionary dict. But i need to manipuate the data as per the *output needed*. im unable to append or modify the dictionary "dict" let me know how to proceed. The xml is being parsed in the main function and the def_2_tree function is used to return a dictionary

```py
def etree_2_dict(element):
    dict = {element.tag: {} if element.attrib else None}
    children = list(element)
    if children:
        dd = defaultdict(list)
        for dc in map(etree_2_dict, children):
            for key, value in dc.items():
                dd[key].append(value)
        dict = {element.tag: {key: value[0] if len(value) == 1 else value
                        for key, value in dd.items()}}
    if element.attrib:
        dict[element.tag].update(( key, value)
                        for key, value in element.attrib.items())

    if element.text:
        text = element.text.strip()
        if children or element.attrib:
            if text:
              dict[element.tag] = text
        else:
            dict[element.tag] = text

    return dict

if __name__ == '__main__':
     element = ET.fromstring('''
    <lcp_info>
      <domain name="d1">
        <rcb template="ec0crb3a2ab1n05x5" instance="sprxccsouth23/mdf_c_v_0_mdf_c_v_c3_r6/mdfc_vcp/clk_sync_dist/i_gclk_make_clk_and_rcb_free/i_ctech_lib_rcb_and.ctech_lib_rcb_and.ctech_lib_rcb_and_dcszo"/>
      </domain>
      <domain name="d2">
        <rcb template="ec0crb3a2ab1n05x5" instance="sprxccsouth23/mdf_c_v_0_mdf_c_v_c3_r6/mdfc_vcp/x12clk_rcb_lcb_mdfc_vcp.i_gclk_make_clk_and_rcb_ph1.i_ctech_lib_rcb_and.ctech_lib_rcb_and.ctech_lib_rcb_and_dcszo"/>
      </domain>
      <domain name="d3">
        <rcb template="ec0crb0a2ab1n09x5" instance="sprxccsouth23/mdf_c_v_0_mdf_c_v_c3_r6/mdfc_vcp/x12clk_free_rcb_lcb_mdfc_vcp.i_gclk_make_clk_and_rcb_ph1.i_ctech_lib_rcb_and.ctech_lib_rcb_and.ctech_lib_rcb_and_dcszo"/>
      </domain>
      <domain name="d4">
        <rcb template="unused_lsr" instance="unused_lsr_4"/>
      </domain>
    <!-- Start LSR chain: sprxccsouth23/mdf_c_v_0_mdf_c_v_c3_r6/mdfc_vcp/lcp_lsr_rd_0_reg/d sprxccsouth23 -->
      <chain name="sprxccsouth_0" enable="sprxccsouth_0_enable" RegOpcode="0x4C" tap="MDF_C_V_0_MDF_C_V_C3_R6_D0_STAP_MDFC_VCP_MDF_C_V_C3_R6_D0">
        <field bitWidth="2">
          <domain_name>d1</domain_name>
        </field>
        <field bitWidth="2">
          <domain_name>d2</domain_name>
        </field>
        <field bitWidth="2">
          <domain_name>d3</domain_name>
        </field>
        <field bitWidth="2">
          <domain_name>d4</domain_name>
        </field>
        <field bitWidth="3"> <!-- deskew deadbits-->
          <domain_name></domain_name>
        </field>
      </chain>
      <chain name="mdf_c_v_0_no_lcp" enable="mdf_c_v_0_no_lcp_enable" RegOpcode="0x4C" tap="MDF_C_V_0_MDF_C_V_C3_R6_D0_STAP_MDFC_VCP_MDF_C_V_C3_R6_D0">
        <field bitWidth="3"> <!-- deskew deadbits-->
          <domain_name></domain_name>
        </field>
      </chain> 
      <enable_function>
       <argument name="X">
         <register tap="MDF_C_V_0_MDF_C_V_C3_R6_D0_STAP_MDFC_VCP_MDF_C_V_C3_R6_D0" RegOpcode="0x4D" name="LCPCFGRTDR">
         </register>
       </argument>
       <enable name="sprxccsouth_0_enable">
         <function>X[0]</function>
       </enable>
       <enable name="mdf_c_v_0_no_lcp_enable">
         <function>X[1]</function>
       </enable>
     </enable_function>
    </lcp_info>
    ''')

    from pprint import pprint
    
    dict = etree_2_dict(element)
    
    pprint(dict)
```

Output needed:

```
\_ 0 -> sprxccsouth_0_enable, 1 -> mdf_c_v_0_no_lcp_enable
    - lcpcfg_opcode: 0x4d
    _ lcprtdr_opcode: 0x4c
    - chain0:
        \_ length: 11
        \_ chain name: sprxccsouth_0 
        \_ domain0:
            \_ domain name: d1
            \_ domain index: 3
            \_ domain size: 2
            \_ domain start bit: 9
            \_ domain end bit: 10
            \_ template name: ec0crb3a2ab1n05x5
            \_ instance name: "sprxccsouth23/mdf_c_v_0_mdf_c_v_c3_r6/mdfc_vcp/clk_syn
        \_ domain1:
            \_ domain name: d2
            \_ domain index: 2
            \_ domain size: 2
            \_ domain start bit: 7
            \_ domain end bit: 8
            \_ template name: ec0crb3a2ab1n05x5
            \_ instance name: "sprxccsouth23/mdf_c_v_0_mdf_c_v_c3_r6/mdfc_vcp/clk_syn
        \_ domain2:
            \_ domain name: d3
            \_ domain index: 1
            \_ domain size:2
            \_ domain start bit: 5
            \_ domain end bit: 6
            \_ template name: ec0crb3a2ab1n05x5
            \_ instance name: "sprxccsouth23/mdf_c_v_0_mdf_c_v_c3_r6/mdfc_vcp/clk_syn
        \_ domain3:
        \_ emptyChain: No 
            \_ domain name: d4
            \_ domain index: 0
            \_ domain size:2
            \_ domain start bit: 3
            \_ domain end bit: 4
            \_ template name: "unused_lsr"
            \_ instance name: "unused_lsr_4"
        \_ domain4:
        \_ emptyChain: Yes
        \_ domain name: 
            \_ domain index: 4
            \_ domain size: 3
            \_ domain start bit: 0
            \_ domain end bit: 2
            \_ template name: 
            \_ instance name: 
    - chain1:
        \_ length: 3
        \_ chain name: mdf_c_v_0_no_lcp 
        \_ domain:
            \_ emptyChain: Yes 
            \_ domain name:
             \_ domain index: 0
             \_ domain size: 3
             \_ domain start bit: 0 
             \_ domain end bit:  2
             \_ template name: 
             \_ instance name:
```

Comment: Did you try xmltodict package? See https://pypi.org/project/xmltodict/

Comment: xmltodict doesnt let you manipulate the data. Im able to return the nested dictionary "dict" but i need to manipuate the data and append it back to dictionary as per the output format. which im having issues with.